# Simple number picking game (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, jquery-click-event

First, hello. Great forum/site here :)

I have been working on my personal site for whole weekend and now I'm stuck with this "game" idea which I would like to add my site. I know HTML and CSS pretty well but I'm quite new with JS/jQuery.

Let me try to explain from user experience what (s)he should be able to do with the "game".

There is **10 numbers from where users selects 3 numbers** and also **2 extra numbers** from new numbers list (11-15). These selected numbers then go to another div (or something). From this point I can do my stuff with PHP. But I'm completly stuck with this part. I know, I know its quite simple but braing must be frozen from coding my site for 48hours :D

Select 5 numbers from these: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
Select 2 additional numbers from there: 11-12-13-14-15

And those selected numbers should be shown with jQuery in div like this:
Normal: 2-3-6-7-8 Extra: 12-14

User can also clear selected numbers (if (s)he wants to select different numbers all together) and/or remove one number and select new one. When the 5/2 **numbers are selected all the other numbers should somehow disable** so user cannot select more than 5/2 numbers.

Also it would be cool if user could **randomly select the numbers** (clicking some button and it automatically selects 5+2 numbers). But I have no clue how this could be done?

Now numbers selecting probably could be done with something like this?

```
//5 numbers
$("#mainNumbers div").click(function) {
var selectedNumber = $(this).text().clone();
$("#selectedMainNumbers").append("<div>"+selectedNumber+"</div>");
}

//2 extra numbers
$("#extraNumbers div").click(function) {
var selectedNumber = $(this).text().clone();
$("#selectedExtraNumbers").append("<div>"+selectedNumber+"</div>");
}
```

Clearing selection maybe like this?

```
$("#clearNumbers").click(function) {
    $("#selectedMainNumbers, #selectedExtraNumbers").empty();
    }
```

Do those look ok? Or could those done better somehow.

And now the part that I have no idea. **How numbers sorting should be done?** Use Arrays? For example, user first clicks number 5 and that is added to the #selectedMainNumbers div and then he selects 2 and its added to #selectedMainNumbers div aswell, and it looks like 8-3 now, but I **would like to have numbers is numeric order always**, so the numbers should be 3-8 format.

**Also how the random number picking should be done? What about the disabling number selecting if user has already selected the needed 5 numbers?**

Phew this is long post. Sorry about that. And hopefully you can give me some hint.. since my brain isnt working atm :/ Thank you. Ask if something isnt clear.

Comment: you dont need to clone a text

Comment: Ah yes that is true. Thanks for noticing that :) But no tips how to do this randomizing etc?

Comment: i have worked about a hour more and improved @Oriol code to be exactly what you wanted including random numbers, winning, "disabling" number selecting. Enjoy!!! - jsfiddle.net/Crn45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ihubip/3/)*

HTML:

```
  <div id="mainNumbers"></div> 
  <div id="extraNumbers"></div>
  <div id="selected_mainNumbers"></div> 
  <div id="selected_extraNumbers"></div>      
  <br />     <button id="generateNumbers">Generate random numbers</button>      
  <br />     <button id="clearNumbers">Clear selected</button>
```

CSS:

```
#mainNumbers, #extraNumbers{
  margin:5px;
  padding:16px;
  background:#345;
}
#mainNumbers div,
#extraNumbers div,
#selected_mainNumbers div,
#selected_extraNumbers div
{
 cursor:pointer;
 display:inline;
 background:#eee;
 padding:5px 10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin:3px;
}
#selected_mainNumbers, #selected_extraNumbers{
  margin-top:5px;
  padding:16px;
  height:20px;
  background:#789;
}
.selectedNum{
  opacity:0.5;
}
#selected_mainNumbers div,
#selected_extraNumbers div{
  opacity:1;
  background:gold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
// generate buttons with numbers
for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
  var appendWhile= i<=10 ?
  $('#mainNumbers').append('<div>'+ i +'</div>') :
  $('#extraNumbers').append('<div>'+ i +'</div>') ; 
}

// create arrays for selected numbers
var mainNumbers=[], extraNumbers=[];

// function print array ///
function printArray(name, arrName){
    $('#selected_'+name).empty();
    for(a=0;a<arrName.length;a++){
       $('#selected_'+name).append('<div>'+ arrName[a]+'</div>');
    }
}

// select function ////////
function selectNum(clickedElement, name, len){
  var arrName = window[name]; // convert string to var
  var num = parseInt( $(clickedElement).text(), 10 );  
  if( arrName.length < len && $.inArray(num,arrName) == -1  ) {
    arrName.push(num);
    arrName.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); // sort numerically
    printArray(name, arrName);
    $(clickedElement).addClass('selectedNum');
  }else{
    $(clickedElement).parent().fadeTo(0,0.3).fadeTo(400,1); // visually alert array is full
  }
}

// remove function ///////////
function removeFromArr(clickedElement,arrName){
  var num = parseInt( $(clickedElement).text(), 10 );
  for(i=0;i<arrName.length;i++){
    if(arrName[i]==num){
       arrName.splice(i,1);
       $(clickedElement).remove(); 
    }
  }
}
// clear function
function clearAll(){
    mainNumbers=[], extraNumbers=[]; // reset arrays
  $('#selected_mainNumbers, #selected_extraNumbers').empty(); // remove selected buttons
  $('.selectedNum').removeClass(); // reset 'selected' states
}

// clicks ////////////////////
$('#mainNumbers, #extraNumbers').on('click','div',function(){
   var len = $(this).parent().attr('id')=='mainNumbers' ? 5 : 2;
   selectNum( $(this), $(this).parent().attr('id'), len );
});

$('#selected_mainNumbers, #selected_extraNumbers').on('click','div',function(){
    var arrName = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('selected_')[1];
    $('#'+arrName).find('div:contains('+$(this).text()+')').removeClass('selectedNum');
    removeFromArr( $(this), window[arrName] );
});

// clear all /////////////////
$('#clearNumbers').click(function(){
   clearAll();
});

// generate random ///////////
$('#generateNumbers').click(function(){
  clearAll();
  
  for(r=0;r<5;r++){
     var n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
     while ($.inArray(n, mainNumbers) > -1){ // loop until no match found
         n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
     }  
     mainNumbers[r] = n;
     $('#mainNumbers div').eq(n-1).addClass('selectedNum');
  }
  
  for(rr=0;rr<2;rr++){
     var nn = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (15-10)+10);
     while ($.inArray(nn, extraNumbers) > -1){
         nn = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (15-10)+10);
     }  
     extraNumbers[rr] = nn;
     $('#extraNumbers div').eq(nn-10-1).addClass('selectedNum');
  }
  
   mainNumbers.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); // sort array
  extraNumbers.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); // sort array
  printArray( 'mainNumbers', mainNumbers );
  printArray('extraNumbers', extraNumbers);
  
});
```

Comment: @user1610229 :) glad you like it! Cheers and happy coding

Answer (score 3):

What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ABetK/ ?

And if you want to send it to the server, use a form: http://jsfiddle.net/ABetK/1/

**Edit:**

It seems I didn't read all the question, so my jsfiddle doesn't do all that [user1610229](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1610229/user1610229) wants.

[Dan Barzilay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361042/dan-barzilay) finished my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Crn45/

Comment: That looks pretty awesome. Have to try it. That is good base atleast. Thanks! Now I just need to figure the random selection still...

Comment: alright very good job there, i have worked about a hour more and improved your code to be exactly what he wanted including random numbers, winning, "disabling" number selecting. Enjoy!!! - http://jsfiddle.net/Crn45/

Comment: @DanBarzilay Ah, it seems I didn't read all the question, only the beginning, haha. Thanks for finishing my code!

Comment: Actually Oriol, your was correct. That is exactly what I was looking. The random button thing what I mentioned, is that user car press button -> it selects randomly main and extra numbers. After user has selected the numbers (or used random button) I send it with form/PHP to backend. But than @DanBarzilay for your efforst too! Awesome :)